# SQL query to split column data into rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having sql table in that I am having 2 fields as `No` and `declaration`

```
Code  Declaration
123   a1-2 nos, a2- 230 nos, a3 - 5nos
```

I need to display the declaration for that code as:

```
Code  Declaration 
123   a1 - 2nos 
123   a2 - 230nos 
123   a3 - 5nos
```

I need to split the column data to rows for that code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For this type of data separation, I would suggest creating a split function:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(MAX))       
as       
begin      
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return 
end;
```

Then to use this in a query you can use an `outer apply` to join to your existing table:

```
select t1.code, s.items declaration
from yourtable t1
outer apply dbo.split(t1.declaration, ',') s
```

Which will produce the result:

```
| CODE |  DECLARATION |
-----------------------
|  123 |     a1-2 nos |
|  123 |  a2- 230 nos |
|  123 |    a3 - 5nos |
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0df5e/2)

Or you can implement a CTE version similar to this:

```
;with cte (code, DeclarationItem, Declaration) as
(
  select Code,
    cast(left(Declaration, charindex(',',Declaration+',')-1) as varchar(50)) DeclarationItem,
         stuff(Declaration, 1, charindex(',',Declaration+','), '') Declaration
  from yourtable
  union all
  select code,
    cast(left(Declaration, charindex(',',Declaration+',')-1) as varchar(50)) DeclarationItem,
    stuff(Declaration, 1, charindex(',',Declaration+','), '') Declaration
  from cte
  where Declaration > ''
) 
select code, DeclarationItem
from cte
```

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer is helpful be sure to accept via the checkmark on the left. It will help future visitors and you will get reputation for accepting! :)

Comment: because of your help 

I am having a result as

Code Declaration 123 a1 - 2nos 123 a2 - 230nos 123 a3 - 5nos 123 a1 - 100nos 123 a3 - 6nos is it possible to sum the duplicates and i need the output to be displayed like this

Code Declaration 123 a1 - 102nos 123 a2 - 230nos 123 a3 - 11nos

Comment: @Affan I answered your other question with a solution on how to total the values.

Comment: please guide me in this post...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917099/subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-in-insert-statement

Answer (score 6):

```
Declare @t Table([Code] int, [Declaration] varchar(32));    
Insert Into @t([Code], [Declaration])
Values(123, 'a1-2 nos, a2- 230 nos, a3 - 5nos')

Select 
    x.[Code]
    ,t.Declaration  
    From
    (
        Select 
        *,
        Cast('<X>'+Replace(t.[Declaration],',','</X><X>')+'</X>' As XML) As record

        From @t t
    )x
    Cross Apply
    ( 
        Select fdata.D.value('.','varchar(50)') As Declaration 
        From x.record.nodes('X') As fdata(D)
    ) t
```

Few times back , I have blogged about the same [Split Function in Sql Server using Set base approach](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code1797-split-function-in-sql-server-using-set-base-approach.aspx)

Also, please visit [Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)blog who is maintaining the answer for the same since the last 15 years.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
declare @col1 varchar(100),@CurentSubString varchar(100)

create table #temp
(
    col1 varchar(50)
)

DECLARE CUR   CURSOR
FOR     SELECT  col1
        FROM    your_table
open    CUR

FETCH   next 
FROM    CUR
INTO    @col1

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    WHILE   CHARINDEX (@col1, ';') <> 0
    BEGIN
    SET @CurentSubString    =   SUBSTRING(@col1,1,CHARINDEX (@col1, ';'))
    SET @col1 = SUBSTRING(@col1,CHARINDEX (@col1, ';')+1,len(@col1))

    insert into #temp
    select @CurentSubString
END


IF CHARINDEX (@col1, ';') = 0 and isnull(@col1,'')!= '' 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #temp
    SELECT @col1
END


FETCH   next 
FROM    CUR
INTO    @col1

END


select  * 
From    #temp

CLOSE   CUR
DEALLOCATE CUR
```