# Subquery returned more than 1 value in insert statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need solution to fix this error Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
I don't have subquery in my insert statement but still I am getting this error.

Code:

```
INSERT INTO enquiries_dtls(confdate,confname,region,enquiry,attendedby,dctname,
                           hospital,contactno,email,addr)
VALUES('10/04/2013',
       'APAO',
       'Delhi',
       'test',
       'test',
       'test',
       'test',
       '123214',
       'abc@abc.com',
       'test')
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[enquiries_dtls]
(
  [sno] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
  [Timestamp] [timestamp] NULL,
  [confdate] [date] NULL,
  [confname] [varchar](max) NULL, 
  [region] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [enquiry] [varchar](max) NULL,
  [attendedby] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [dctname] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [hospital] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [contactno] [int] NULL,
  [email] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [addr] [varchar](max) NULL,
  [stsupdate] [varchar](max) NULL,
  [dtupdate] [date] NULL, 
  [closingdate] [date] NULL,
  [clsedby] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [revenue] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [apprstatus] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [clsed] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [enqId] [varchar](50) NULL
);
```

Comment: Is enquiries_dtls a table or a view?

Comment: is there more code it it?

Comment: Where are you running the code and getting the error?  If that is the full code, why does it have double quotes inside of the strings?  If you take your code and run it in SSMS does it work?

Comment: sorry that is the syntax which i edited...this is my code insert into enquiries_dtls(confdate,confname,region,enquiry,attendedby,dctname,hospital,cont‌​actno, email,addr) values('10/04/2013','APAO','Delhi', 'test', 'test', 'test123', 'testname', '12324', 'abc@abc.com', 'tezsteateataetae')

Comment: i am just inserting the data through input form..but i am getting this error subquery returned...but i dont have subquery in my application

Comment: @Affan Are you sure it is this code that is causing the error and not some other code?  If you run this insert alone do you get any errors?  Do you have any triggers on the table?

Comment: Take that code that you put in the question, and run it in SQL Server Management Studio. Do you get the error?

Comment: I don't have triggers in my table...i am running this insert alone..i am getting the error

Comment: @Affan Are you sure there are no triggers on the table?  This code is working see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0e9c/1

Comment: Thoroughly checked..there is no Trigger in it...i dont know why i am getting the same error

Comment: thanks a lot for all your try...created a new table and finished the thing