# Count number of occurrences of keyword in comma separated column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a column which stores data like this:

Product:
    product1,product2,product5
    product5,product7
    product1

What I would like to do is count the number of occurrences there are of product1, product2, etc. but where the record contains multiple products I want it to double count them.

So for the above example the totals would be:
    product1: 2
    product2: 1
    product5: 2
    product7: 1

How can I achieve this?

I was trying something like this:

```
    select count(case when prodcolumn like '%product1%' then 'product1' end) from myTable
```

This gets me the count for product1 appears but how do I extend this to go through each product?

I also tried something like this:

```
    select new_productvalue, count(new_productvalue) from OpportunityExtensionBase 
    group by new_ProductValue
```

But that lists all different combinations of the products which were found and how many times they were found...

These products don't change so hard coding it is ok...

EDIT: here is what worked for me.

```
WITH Product_CTE (prod) AS 
(SELECT
  n.q.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
    FROM (SELECT cast('<r>'+replace(new_productvalue, ';', '</r><r>')+'</r>' AS xml) FROM table) AS s(XMLCol)
      CROSS APPLY s.XMLCol.nodes('r') AS n(q)
    WHERE n.q.value('.', 'varchar(50)') <> '')
    SELECT prod, count(*) AS [Num of Opps.] FROM Product_CTE GROUP BY prod
```

Comment: next time avoid comma separated values in a column

Comment: Completely agree with you but this is what I am given and have to work with unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lousy, lousy data structure, but sometimes one must make do with that.  You should have a separate table storing each pair product/whatever pair -- that is the relational way.

```
with prodref as (
      select 'product1' as prod union all
      select 'product2' as prod union all
      select 'product5' as prod union all
      select 'product7' as prod
     )
select p.prod, count(*)
from prodref pr left outer join
     product p
     on ','+p.col+',' like '%,'+pr.prod+',%'
group by p.prod;
```

This will be quite slow on a large table.  And, the query cannot make use of standard indexes.  But, it should work.  If you can restructure the data, then you should.

Comment: I agree, having a comma separated value is definitely not something I like but this is what I am faced with in this scenario. Thanks for the code but I ended up finding something online that worked better for me, updated my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind all you need if one split function
[SQL query to split column data into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527537/sql-query-to-split-column-data-into-rows?rq=1)

hope after this you can manage .