# Split comma delimited string and select top "SearchTags" ordered by count

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm working with the following dataset:

```
ID  SearchTags
1   Cats,Birds,Dogs,Snakes,Roosters
2   Mice,Chickens,Cats,Lizards
3   Birds,Zebras,Sheep,Horses,Monkeys,Chimps
4   Lions,Tigers,Bears,Chickens
5   Cats,Goats,Pandas
6   Birds,Zebras,Sheep,Horses
7   Rats,Dogs,Hawks,Eagles,Tigers
8   Cats,Tigers,Dogs,Pandas
9   Dogs,Beavers,Sharks,Vultures
10  Cats,Bears,Bats,Leopards,Chickens
```

I need to query out a list of the most popular SearchTags.

I have a query which will return the most popular SearchTags but it returns the whole list of words. (which I expected). Is it possible to split the SearchTags column on (,) and generate a list of the most popular tags so that I end up with a list/count as follows?:

```
Cats    5
Dogs    4
Chickens    3
Tigers  3
Bears   2
Sharks  1
etc...
```

instead of what I get now:

```
Cats,Birds,Dogs,Snakes,Roosters 1
Dogs,Beavers,Sharks,Vultures    1
Cats,Bears,Bats,Leopards,Chickens 1
etc...
```

Here's the query that returns the list of words.

```
SELECT SearchTags, COUNT(*) AS TagCount
FROM Animals
GROUP BY SearchTags
ORDER BY TagCount DESC
```

I'm using SQL Server. I'd prefer a query but can create a stored procedure if needed.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13527642/772086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tagged the question with C# and LINQ, if you have the data in a `DataTable` then you can do:

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromDB();
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(r => r.Field<string>("SearchTags").Split(','))
               .SelectMany(r => r)
               .GroupBy(r => r)
               .Select(grp => new
                   {
                       Key = grp.Key,
                       Count = grp.Count()
                   });
```

If you have LINQ TO SQL set up then you can do:

```
var query = db.YourTable
               .Select(r=> r.SearchTags)
               .AsEnumerable()
               .Where(r=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r))
               .Select(r => r.Split(','))
               .SelectMany(r => r)
               .GroupBy(r => r)
               .Select(grp => new
                   {
                       Key = grp.Key,
                       Count = grp.Count()
                   });

           });
```

This will load all the `SearchTags`  in memory and then you would be able to apply `Split`.

You can also filter out null or empty string values for `SearchTags` at your database end like:

```
var query = db.YourTable
               .Where(r=> r.SearchTags != null && r.SearchTags.Trim() != "")
               .Select(r=> r.SearchTags)
               .AsEnumerable()
               .Select(r => r.Split(','))
               .SelectMany(r => r)
               .GroupBy(r => r)
               .Select(grp => new
                   {
                       Key = grp.Key,
                       Count = grp.Count()
                   });

           });
```

The above will filter out the null or empty strings/only white spaces, from the returned collection at the database end and would work more efficiently.

For filtering out dates do:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-14);
var query = db.YourTable
               .Where(r=> r.SearchTags != null && 
                      r.SearchTags.Trim() != "" &&
                      r.MediaDate >= dt)
               .Select(r=> r.SearchTags)
               .AsEnumerable()
               .Select(r => r.Split(','))
               .SelectMany(r => r)
               .GroupBy(r => r)
               .Select(grp => new
                   {
                       Key = grp.Key,
                       Count = grp.Count()
                   });

           });
```

Comment: I tried implementing your LINQ to SQL example but get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: DB.Animals.Select(r=>r.SearchTags) returns results so the first part of the example is ok. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Maddhacker24, there could be records where `SearchTags` is null in your database, for that just add a filter after `AsEnumerable`, I have modified the code for LINQ to SQL `.Where(r=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r))`

Comment: Bingo, that was it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Maddhacker24, You are welcome, I also added one more option to filter out null/empty string values at database end, this will give you a better performance, if your records include a lot of data with null values for search tags.

Comment: I have a date column in my dataset as well. Rather then pull the most popular search tags for the entire dataset how could I fit in a > "somedate" clause so that i only return the most popular search tags after a particular date. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Maddhacker24, if it is a `DateTime` type column, then you can add a filter before `Select` like `.Where(r=> r.Field<DateTime>("somedate") > new Date(2014,08,14))`

Comment: Here's my full query that is returing results (I added OrderByDescending): 
MediaTable.Select(r=> r.SearchTags).AsEnumerable().Where(r=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r)).Select(r => r.Split(',')).SelectMany(r => r).GroupBy(r => r).Select(grp => new { Key = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() }).OrderByDescending(r=>r.Count)

I'm having trouble fitting this 'where' statement into it.
.Where(r=> r.MediaDate >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-14))

Comment: @Maddhacker24, modify your Where clause after AsEnumerable to `.Where(r=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r) && .MediaDate >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-14))`

Comment: You can also add a similar check before `AsEnumerable` but calculate that date in a local variable like `DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-14);` and then pass then in your LINQ TO SQL version before `AsEnumerable` like `.Where(r=> r != null && r.Trim() != "" && r.MediaDate >= dt)`. This will further improve the performance as this check will be performed at Database end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59763/discussion-between-maddhacker24-and-habib).

Comment: Trying both of those resulted in the following error: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'MediaDate' and no extension method 'MediaDate' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Comment: @Maddhacker24, are you trying LINQ To SQL version the last code snippet ?

Comment: This is what I just tried with the same error. For ease of use I just used a static date ----  MediaTable.Select(r=> r.SearchTags).Where(r=> r != null && r.Trim() != "" && r.MediaDate >= "07/01/2014").AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Split(',')).SelectMany(r => r).GroupBy(r => r).Select(grp => new { Key = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() }).OrderByDescending(r=>r.Count)

Comment: @Maddhacker24, your where clause should be before Select, like `MediaTable.Where(r=> r.SearchTags != null && r.SearchTags.Trim() != "" && r.MediaDate >= dt).Select(r=> r.SearchTags).AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Split(',')).SelectMany(r => r).GroupBy(r => r).Select(grp => new { Key = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() }).OrderByDescending(r=>r.Count)`, and `DateTime` should be an object.

Comment: @Maddhacker24, try the last code snippet in my answer, Just modified it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want TSQL...

There are numerous TSQL functions for splitting strings, but anything using XQuery are by far the fastest versus the plethora of looping functions.

I use something similar to this in a production system on a table with a 10-15K CSV values, and it runs in seconds, versus an old looping function which sometimes took up to a minute.

Anyway, here's a quick demo to get you going.

```
DECLARE @DATA TABLE (ID INT, SEARCHTAGS VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @DATA
SELECT 1,'Cats,Birds,Dogs,Snakes,Roosters' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Mice,Chickens,Cats,Lizards' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Birds,Zebras,Sheep,Horses,Monkeys,Chimps' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Lions,Tigers,Bears,Chickens' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'Cats,Goats,Pandas' UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'Birds,Zebras,Sheep,Horses' UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'Rats,Dogs,Hawks,Eagles,Tigers' UNION ALL
SELECT 8,'Cats,Tigers,Dogs,Pandas' UNION ALL
SELECT 9,'Dogs,Beavers,Sharks,Vultures' UNION ALL
SELECT 10,'Cats,Bears,Bats,Leopards,Chickens'

;WITH TagList AS
(
SELECT ID, Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS String
FROM  (SELECT ID, 
              CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(CAST(SEARCHTAGS AS VARCHAR), ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
       FROM @DATA) AS A 
CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)

SELECT TOP (10) String, COUNT(*) AS [SearchCount]
FROM TagList
GROUP BY String
ORDER BY [SearchCount] DESC
```

NB: Anything to do with string manipulation is almost always faster if you can handle it in c#... so the answer by Habib would probably be more efficient than a TSQL solution.