# Joining a table based on comma separated values

Tags: sql-server

How can I join two tables, where one of the tables has multiple comma separated values in one column that reference an `id` in another column?

**1st table**

```
Name    | Course Id
====================
Zishan  | 1,2,3                                           
Ellen   | 2,3,4
```

**2nd table**

```
course id | course name 
=======================
   1      |  java
   2      |  C++
   3      |  oracle
   4      |  dot net
```

Comment: Please normalized your DB structure!

Comment: When you combine multiple values into a single field, they become a single value.  Perhaps you can create a view which parses the data into an actual relational table and then perform your join with that view?

Comment: normalize like this (Zishan,1),(Zishan,2),(Zishan,3) and 
(Ellen ,2),(Ellen ,3),(Ellen ,4)

Comment: Normalising your data would be the better option, but there is an answer here that should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527537/sql-query-to-split-column-data-into-rows

Comment: This is a database design error. It is critical that you fix it and not use a hack to get the data out. This will permanently affect performance and it will get much worse as your data grows. Basically this is a cancer at the heart of your system and if you do not fix it, then you will find that over time the problem will get larger and much much harder to fix. You should not allow this serious design flaw to stand unless this is software bought from a third party and database design this incompetent would lead me to stop using any software that company designed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [join comma delimited data column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507239/join-comma-delimited-data-column)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe this uglyness, I have not checked results:

```
select names.name, courses.course_name
from names inner join courses
    on ',' + names.course_ids + ',' like '%,' + cast(courses.course_id as nvarchar(20)) + ',%'
```

Comment: For all that this is an ugly hack, I love that it is an incredibly simple way of getting the desired results.  For people who don't have the option of normalising the database schema, this is a great workaround.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your Database structure **is not** normalized and should have been. Since it is already set up this way , here's how to solve the issue.

You'll need a function to split your string first:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STRING(str VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), pos INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)

     RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos),
            LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos-1)) + 1), delim, '');
```

Then you'll need to create a view in order to make up for your structure:

```
CREATE VIEW database.viewname AS 
    SELECT SPLIT_STRING(CourseID, ',', n) as firstField,
           SPLIT_STRING(CourseID, ',', n) as secondField,
           SPLIT_STRING(CourseID, ',',n) as thirdField 
    FROM 1stTable;
```

*Where **n** is the nth item in your list.*

Now that you have a view which generates your separated fields, you can make a normal join on your view, just use your view like you would use a table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourView 
JOIN table1.field ON table2.field
```

However since I don't think you'll always have 3 values in your second field from your first table you'll need to tweak it a little more.

**Inspiration of my answer from:**

[SQL query to split column data into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527537/sql-query-to-split-column-data-into-rows)
and
[Equivalent of explode() to work with strings in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: Personally I don't like create logic at DB level.

Comment: @mpacheco: i totally agree, but sometimes people just want to watch the world burn

Answer (score 0):

SELECT f.name,s.course_name FROM table1 AS f
INNER JOIN table2 as s ON f.course_id IN (s.course_id)

Answer (score -4):

Use the Below Query For Solution

```
Select * from table_2 t2 INNER JOIN table_1 t1 on t1.Course Id = t2.course id
```