# Select all cell values of a single row table and list it as separate row in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've a table like this

```
ID        col1         col2        col3      col4
---------------------------------------------------
1          a            b           c         d
2          e            f           g         h
```

So if I pass the ID 2 it should return all the colum values as separate rows as this

```
Colum     Value
---------------------
ID        2
Col1      e
col2      f
col3      g
col4      h
```

So all the cells of that single rows been splitted as separate rows.

How can I accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it with `unpivot` and `union all`.

```
select 'id' as colu,cast(id as varchar(255)) as val from t where id=2
union all
select colu,val
from t
unpivot (val for colu in (col1,col2,col3,col4)) u
where id=2
```

Comment: Any possibility of wiithout specifying the column names. I mean all collumns

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross apply as below:

```
Select Id as [Column], [Value]  from yourcols
    cross apply (values(col1), (col2), (col3), (col4)) rws([Value])
    where Id = 2
```

Comment: Any possibility of wiithout specifying the column names. I mean all collumns

Comment: I dont think so... Without mentioning columnname how engine know what data you need to unpivot... that you can generate dynamically using information_schema or sys.columns rite?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer the below  stack over flow link     [SQL query to split column data into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527537/sql-query-to-split-column-data-into-rows)

found the question identical as yours.

Comment: Hope you go through that question.. Its actually splitting the second cell data into rows