# Splitting and transposing table data using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, pivot

I have data in the following structure

```
 ID   Sub_ID
 123  '1;2;3'
```

I would like to create a table with the following structure

```
ID Sub_ID
123 1
123 2
123 3
```

Is there any way to process this task on a Microsoft SQL-Server?

THX
Lazloo

Comment: I found a other question that handles the same problem: [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you older version then SQL Server 2016 you need to create your own split function:

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[Tbl_Fn_Split](
    @InputText VARCHAR(8000) 
  , @Delimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ' ' -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (Result VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
DECLARE @aResult VARCHAR(8000)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@InputText,0) <> 0
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @aResult=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@InputText,1,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@InputText,0)-1))),
        @InputText=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@InputText,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@InputText,0)+LEN(@Delimiter),LEN(@InputText))))

    IF LEN(@aResult) > 0
        INSERT INTO @List SELECT @aResult
    END

    IF LEN(@InputText) > 0
        INSERT INTO @List SELECT @InputText 

    RETURN

END
```

Then you can use it with your query using CROSS APPLY :

```
SELECT * FROM tTable  T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Tbl_Fn_Split](T.Sub_Id,';')) S
```

Comment: Oh no... This way of string splitting is really slow... And *multi-statement* UDFs are really slow... Avoid loops, cursors, scalar functions and *multi-statement* UDFs if possible... There are much better approaches with XML or recursice CTEs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or later, then [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is one option here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, value
    FROM yourTable
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Sub_ID, ';')
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY value;
```

[image]

### Demo

If you are using an earlier version of SQL Server, then [here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527537/sql-query-to-split-column-data-into-rows) to a canonical SO question which can help.  If you have this need long term, maybe consider upgrading.

Comment: Unfortunately, the SQL Version I use is too old

Comment: @LazlooXp [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527537/sql-query-to-split-column-data-into-rows) is a link to another SO question which gives other options which can work on earlier versions.