# SQL create function syntax error in hue impala

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I'm a newbie to SQL.
I'm trying to create a function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13527642/3415167) in Hue impala.
I've change `[dbo].[Split]` to `dbo.split` as there was error.
But now, I'm getting a different error:

```
AnalysisException: Syntax error in line49:undefined: create function dbo.split(@input varchar(max), @delimi... ^ Encountered: Unexpected character Expected: ARRAY, BIGINT, BINARTY, BOOLEAN, CHAR, DATE, DATETIME, DECIMAL, REAL, FLOAT, INTEGER, MAP, SMALLINT, STING, STRUCT, TIMESTAMP, TINYINT, VARCHAR CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
```

and in the code editor, I'm getting a red line under `varchar` among `create function dbo.split(@string varchar(max), @delimiter char(1))`

I'm not sure what's wrong with my create function code.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to below link for how to create functions in Impala. Creating user-defined functions are not very common in impala.
https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_create_function.html
You can also use in-built split functions like split_part.
`split_part(string source, string delimiter, bigint n)`
`select split_part('x,y,z',',',1) out;
+-----------------------------+
| out |
+-----------------------------+
| x                           |
+-----------------------------+`